# Aren't such limit expressions as $\lim_{x\to 3} (5x-6)$ informal?

Tags: calculus, analysis

The limit is first defined with respect to functions.

Example (Abbott, 2015, *Understanding Analysis*, p. 116):

[image]

But shortly after, this and many other calculus/analysis texts then quietly slip into talking about such expressions as "$\lim_{x\to 3} (5x-6)$" (or "$\lim_{x\to 3} 1$", "$\lim_{x\to 3} (1+\sin x)$", "$\lim_{x\to 3} x^2$", etc.).

But aren't such expressions informal?

Shouldn't we instead first define a function $f$ where $f(x)=5x-6$ and the domain of $f$ has $3$ as a limit point, then speak of $\lim_{x\to 3} f(x)$?

And does it not matter what the domain of $f$ is? I think this doesn't matter in the $5x-6$ example.

But consider "$\lim_{x\to 3} (1+\mathbf{1}_\mathbb{Q}(x))$":

- We can define $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=1+\mathbf 1_{\mathbb Q}(x)$. Then $\lim_{x\to 3} f(x)=2$.
- Or we can define $g:\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=1+\mathbf 1_{\mathbb Q}(x)$. Then $\lim_{x\to 3} g(x)=1$.

So, is "$\lim_{x\to 3} (1+\mathbf{1}_\mathbb{Q}(x))$" $2$ or $1$?

Comment: It is a matter of conventions. Generally, the domain is assumed to be an interval of the real line around $3$. If you want to restrict the domain  to rationals, irratioinals etc, you have to mention that explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

When the domain of the function is not given, the convention is to adopt the largest region (here, within the set of real numbers) in which the function is well-defined. So, for your question the domain is the set of real numbers.
The limit in your question does not exist. For any candidate limit $\ell$, take $\varepsilon = 1/2$ and notice that for any interval $(3-\delta,3+\delta)$ the given function assumes values $1$ and $2$ (any such interval has rational as well as irrational numbers), so that $|f(x)-\ell|$ cannot be made less that $1/2$ for all $x$ in that interval.

Alternatively, we can argue that no limit $\ell$ exists because as $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ approaches $3$, we get the limit $2$ and as $x \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ approaches $3$ we get $1$ (uniqueness of the limit would be violated).